# How to obtain count of update records from Hive

Tags: jdbc, hive, hiveql

I am working with hive driver in which the `executeUpdate()` record does not return the affected record count. Is there any alternate way in which this can be obtained? We need to get the effected record value for further processing.

Comment: If I had to guess, the reason the Hive JDBC driver doesn't return it, is that Hive doesn't have a way to give this information. So you are probably out of luck here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am not mistaken Hive does not show (or even know?!) the number of updated records. Therefore extracting this directly is likely not going to work.

**Workaround**

1. First run a count query using the exact where statement and log the result
2. Then do the actual update

Naturally this incurs significant overhead.